# Where can I increase color depth in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient

I'm working with a gradient in Illustrator, but there is banding in gradient. I'm trying to increase the color depth, but I can't find the color depth setting.

If there are any other methods to remove banding, I'm open to those ideas too.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your gradient in your question? It may be useful to better help solve your situation. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Hi Shirish Maharjan, maybe it's a problem of color types used in the gradient, we can see that in a screenshot.

Comment: Please add info about the gradient, gradient file wold be the best. 1st color value, 2nd color value, color space, length of gradient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no color depth setting in illustrator. you can try to add some color grain or noise to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. But you can not.

In the end, Normally Illustrator, or most vector programs for that matter only works with 256 levels of values. Even when working CMYK values, that are represented on a 0-100 scale, are using 256 values.

But the thing is it does not matter that you use for example a 16 bit per channel image. The values are going to be translated to a 256 depth on the output.

Comment: How does this really differ from my answer?

Comment: I tried to add some information about the values on the RGB and CMYK scales. :oP